# template literals with import images

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

```
<img alt="placeholder" src={ALL.file1.default}></img>
```

The above works and renders a picture.

I'm trying to use template literals to make the 1 a dynamic variable.

```
<img alt="placeholder" src={`${ALL.file`${randomnum}`.default}`}></img>
<img alt="placeholder" src={ALL.file`${randomnum}`.default}></img>
```

Both these don't seem to work as I get an error

```
Attempted import error: 'file' is not exported from '../images/icons/' (imported as 'ALL').
```

I imported all the pictures using a index.js in the images folders exporting all of them individually then importing them with:

```
import * as ALL from "../images/icons/";
```

Am I using the template literal incorrectly, or does it have something to do with the import conflicting method?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You seem to be looking for `<img alt="placeholder" src={ALL['file'+randomnum].default} />`? It's just a dynamic property access, no template literal magic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember when you use dynamic properties you need to use the `[]` syntax.

In your example, it would go like this:

```
<img alt="placeholder" src={ALL[`file${randomnum}`].default}></img>
```